# How to pass special characters as query string in url

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to pass special characters as querystring in url as part of GET request. I am constructiong that string in javascript function.

```
var queryString = "list=ABC-48+12&level=first";
```

Then I append the string to url as part of request which goes to struts action class. In the action class I get the "list" value as `"ABC-48 12"`, the `"+"` character is not passed. 
How to pass special characters in the string as part of url and get back in the java class?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are we talking about? The tags say c# and javascript, your question says java and the code can be either c# or javascript...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression with the global option set as the first parameter instead of a string: (in regular expressions "+" is a special character, so we have to escape it with a backslash.)

safeQueryString = safeQueryString.replace(/+/g, '%2B');

Comment: Really? And that's the accepted answer? Oh my Holly God! What if the value contained the `&` character? Or the `=` character? you would have written one more regex to it?

Answer (score 12):

You should url encode it using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function:

```
var queryString = 
    "list=" + encodeURIComponent("ABC-48+12") + 
    "&level=" + encodeURIComponent("first");
```

This function will take care of properly encoding your query string parameter values:

```
list=ABC-48%2B12&level=first
```